# change superclass' property value

Tags: objective-c, ios, subclass, subview

I got class

```
@interface PlayScene : UIView
```

with some properties in it (here are some of them)

```
@property (readwrite, assign) int Figure1;
@property (readwrite, assign) int Figure2;
@property (readwrite, assign) int Figure3;
```

and I got a subView that is called in PlayScene

```
@interface gameOverMenu : PlayScene <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and I need to get somehow those properties in my subclass. Actually I need to set them equal to 0 so that "Play Again" button works properly.

Comment: did you mean @interface gameOverMenu : PlayScene <UITextFieldDelegate>

Comment: well yea, I guess it should be like that, but how can I get properties? Yea it is totally better to minus my question than to explain...

Comment: So what happened when you tried accessing the properties from an instance of that `gameOverMenu` subclass?

Comment: damn I didn't understand at once that : PlayScene solves the problem

Comment: @Alexander I didn't downvote your question, did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having same issue the original question was :

```
@interface gameOverMenu : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

He solved it by changing it to :

```
@interface GameOverMenu : PlayScene <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Comment: Note that the class should be named `GameOverMenu`.

Comment: well I got a new problem now, all properties were assigned as "read write", but when I try to change them like [self Figure1] =0; there is  an error "assigning to 'readonly' return result of an objective-c message not allowed"

Comment: @Alexander normally you'd open another question for that but here is how you can fix that issue @property `(strong, nonatomic)`